# Copy and rename directory

Tags: c#, filesystems

I'm trying to modify this code to copy and rename (instead of just move) multiple directories.  I have a CSV file that has 2 columns. The "original folder name" and the "new folder name".

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

string csv = "csv path";
string sourcedir = @"C:\temp1\";
string targetdir = @"C:\temp2\";

string[] items = File.ReadAllLines(csv);
foreach(var item in items)
{
    string oldname = item.Split(';')[0];
    string newname = item.Split(';')[1];

    Directory.Move(sourcedir +oldname, targetdir +newname);
}
```

Comment: is there a function to copy the folder instead of cut? (directory.move)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When *source*-folder doesn't contain nested folders then use [this way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-copy-delete-and-move-files-and-folders#example):

```
string csv = "csv path";
string sourcedir = @"C:\temp1\";
string targetdir = @"C:\temp2\";

var items = File.ReadAllLines(csv);

foreach(var item in items)
{
    var paths = item.Split(";");
    var sourcePath = Path.Combine(sourcedir, paths[0]);
    var targetPath = Path.Combine(targetdir, paths[1]);

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);

    var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

    foreach (string s in files)
    {
        var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
        var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

        System.IO.File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you need to use recursive traverse through nested folders - see example [MS docs 'How to: Copy directories'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-copy-directories).

Comment: @vladamir - thanks.  I have looked at the MS article but im a bit lost.  I have a loop that if a file doesn't exist in the destination then MOVE, otherwise, DONT MOVE.  However, if the directory has a subdirectory that has a file, it doesn't pick it up.  Any ideas?  Thanks!